# android insert into activity stack

Tags: android, android-intent, stack

Here is the question:
Let's say the activity stack consist of A->B->C.

If user followed the order eg: Start A -> B -> C, pressing back button will cause C->B->A.
However, if user entered directly into activity C (eg: via notification), pressing back button will cause the app to close, instead of going into B->A.

How do I insert the into the activity stack to become A->B->C, so that when user pressed back at C, it will always back to B.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just overide the onBackPressed() method and startactivity B in activityc and startactivity a in activity b.

in activty c have these code::

```
public void onBackPressed(){
startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class));
finish();
}
```

and in activity b have these code::

```
public void onBackPressed(){
startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityA.class));
finish();
}
```

and in activity a have these code::

```
public void onBackPressed(){
finish();
}
```

Comment: does this breaks the android activity stack order? It should finish current activity and back to previous, not starting another new activity.

Comment: This is one of the good solutions.. Its better to use fragments instead of activities for better performance..