# Insert activity into root stack

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have an app where the main activity flow is A -> B. However the user may launch the app directly into B, in which case it's the only activity in the stack. I'd like the user to launch into B and still be able to reach A either through back or through the "pop stack" in the upper left corner.

The best solution for the back key is about rewriting onBackPressed(), and I understand that the "pop stack" button is supposed to slightly differ in meaning. However I'm genuinely curious about what it takes to really have to get a A -> B stack without having displayed A in the first place - that is, no "quickly flash A in the screen and launch B as fast as possible" allowed.

Comment: The best solution is to let the user launch B from A, but never B directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. As you said,  manipulation of B's onBackPressed() where you can start activity A through intent and finish() activity B. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163769/android-insert-into-activity-stack) there is some sample code that you can tailor to your needs.
2. Launch activity A whenever users requests either A or B. Then in the onCreate of your A identify the intention of the user and either call activity B (and add A in stack) or continue by showing A's UI. Note that Activities become visible only after their onCreate has finished, thus there won't be any flashes that will disrupt the user. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart) for more information on Activity lifecycle.

Comment: Cool! solution 2 is exactly what I needed to know, although I was looking for another solution that wouldn't fit so smoothly: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html. That's why SO is invaluable so many times.